# How "nice" determines amount of cpu resource to give

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit, nice, process-priority

Is there a particular formula to calculate the amount of cpu resources that is allocated for a process when you "nice" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what scheduler you are using.

See for example

- http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html
- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101760

Also [source code of Linux scheduler](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob_plain;f=kernel/sched.c;hb=ee715087024b91a6ceb85ba2d02f6c35d354a48c).

It's rather complicated by it's nature (trying to optimize CPU time, performance and responsiveness).